# re-directing in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

on succefull login, i am trying to re-direct the user to another website.  The code below, doesn't work and can't figure why.

I have used; window.location.href, document.location.href and window.location.replace too.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title></title> 


<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" type="text/css">
<script src="login.js">



    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" value="" required/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" value="" required/>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>


    <script>

    function myFunction(){

        var uName= document.getElementById("username").value;
        //alert(uName);
        var pwd= document.getElementById("password").value;
        //alert(pwd);

        var result = loginCheck(uName, pwd);//loginCheck function external 

        //if true             
        if(result==true){

           //re-direct to stack overflow
            window.location.href= "http://stackoverflow.com";

        }

        else{

            alert("you have failed");
        }

    }



    </script>
```

Comment: what happens when you click the button? what is showing up on the console? any error?

Comment: what is the value of `result`? above the `if` statement do a `console.log(result)`

Comment: the problem is within the function, you did not post. The above code works perfectly, `loginCheck()` is the problem

Comment: but why should it be a problem as that function sits in an external java file.  the if condition returns true as well as I have alert'ed the result var.  so, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Is `loginCheck` an asynchronous function?  If so, you need to somehow wait for the response before checking the result.

Comment: here is my function login  function loginCheck(user, pass){
    
    var userName="admin";
    var passWord="admin";
    
    if(userName==user && passWord==pass){
        return true;
    }
    
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: changing the button type seems to have done it which I would never guessed it.  many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your button is trying to sumbit a form. this might be a weird solution but change the button `type` attribute to anything but *submit*.

for example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should do the whole action in jquery document.ready or an anonymous function. Secondly, in the loginCheck definition, use the callback to call the result check

```
  <button id="buttonId">Login</button>
```

Then in js

```
;(function(){
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var uName= document.getElementById("username").value;
    //alert(uName);
    var pwd= document.getElementById("password").value;
    //alert(pwd);

   loginCheck(uName, pwd, function(){
    //if true             
    if(result==true){
       //re-direct to stack overflow
        window.location.href= "http://stackoverflow.com";
    }
    else{
        alert("you have failed");
    }
    }); 
});
})();
```

Add callback in function parameters and call when done checking

Answer (score 0):

To redirect use window.location

```
window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```